# f-string affected by quotation

Tags: python, python-3.6, f-string

```
alien_o = {"Colour" : "Green"}
print(f"The colour is now {alien_o["Colour"]}.")
```

What's wrong with these lines of code? The closing bracket and the curly bracket is affected by the quotes, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Don't use double quotes inside expression

Comment: Use single quotes `'` or triple quotes `'''` for the f-string. Something like this `print(f'The colour is now {alien_o["Colour"]}.')`. The rule is: if you are using single quotes outside, use double quotes inside and vice-versa.

Comment: Yup. You can't do backslashes. F-strings are super convenient, but they do have some limitations, which are fortunately easy to manage

Comment: Note: In Python 3.12, this code works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It mixes up the `"`, try using `'Colour'` instead of `"Colour"`.

Because it thinks that the format string is `f"The colour is now {alien_o["`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Straight-forward answer:**

f-strings use quotation marks as delimiters, which is why including quotes in the interpolated element {} confuses the interpreter. Python thinks that you may be trying to end the f-string with the interior quotes.

> The closing bracket and the curly bracket is affected by the quotes

If you care about the semantics of the error, it's actually not the closing bracket that's affected, but rather your {variable} is chopped in half.

As a result, this earlier part:

```
The colour is now {alien_o[
```

is interpreted by print() as a string **since it is technically wrapped by quotes**, as opposed to a dict key interpolated (inserted) into a f-string, which was likely your intent in wrapping it with {}.

However, python doesn't know what to do with the **rest** of the message, and throws an error before it can do anything else.

That's why you are likely seeing:

```
SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '['
```

**One possible solution:**

If you ask me, in your case the most straightforward way to overcome this confusion is to eliminate the need for quotation marks.

```
alien_o = {"Colour" : "Green"}
key = "Colour"
print(f"The colour is now {alien_o[key]}.")

# or, if you want to make it more generalized:
print(f"The {key} is now {alien_o[key]}.")
```

If that's *still* not satisfying, it doesn't have to feel so plain jane:

```
alien_o = {"Colour" : "Green", 
           "Face" : "Toothy", 
           "Shape" : "None", 
           "Transparency" : "Opaque"}

# dict.keys() gets all dict keys for you
# alien_o is your dict, so for you it is alien_o.keys()

keys = [i for i in alien_o.keys() if len(i)<7]
print(f"The alien's features are now {[alien_o[key] for key in keys]}.")
```

Above I used a list comprehension to add potential criteria to the keys variable *before* passing it to an f-string.

**You can also look into:**

- alternate Python string interpolation methods
- asci codes for other controversial characters (newlines, specifying strings for simple functions in f-strings (my personal favorite)

One example of calling the ASCI character code of a period in an f-string:

```
filename = 'file.txt'
print(f'The name of the file without extension is {filename.split(chr(46)})[0]
# print(f'The name of the file without extension is {filename.split('.'})[0]
```

The commented-out bottom line would would fail for the same reason as your code above.